# latex default settings paper, font, size, page numbering

Tags: latex-misc

I'm having a hard time grasping the structure of my "TeX" installation ...

it is Tex Live 2010. I'm a european user - so some default settings are included ...

but I need the most general, most uncustomized, most geniue, maybe most US version of LaTeX.

Why does it make no difference: `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}`  and `\documentclass{article}` on my system?

Why do I get `\thispagestyle{empty}` still a page number at the bottom center for my title page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX Live adjusts settings for the *output* paper as A4; on the other hand, LaTeX uses as default the option `letterpaper` for setting the page shape (just because it was born in the US).

With `\documentclass{article}` you'll get a page set for Letter paper imposed on A4 paper, which is wrong.

Just to show some values (**article** class)

```
                 letterpaper   a4paper
\textwidth       345pt         345pt
\textheight      550pt         598pt
\oddsidemargin   62pt          53pt
```

You see that the page height is larger for A4 paper, while the left margin is smaller, in order to accommodate the same line width. So, always use the `a4paper` option.

You can remove the page number by saying `\thispagestyle{empty}` *after* `\maketitle`, as this command issues `\thispagestyle{plain}`.

Comment: +1 - It's very useful to have these numbers! Where did you find them?

Comment: @user4929 Either you look in `size10.clo` or use a package such as `layout`